# Is there a way to CREATE/DROP groups in redshift with IF NOT EXISTS functionality?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have multiple environments in aws redshift. Some of which have a specific created group and others which don't.

I need to create the group in all environments in one deployment. Ideally I would use

`CREATE GROUP IF NOT EXISTS GROUPX`

`If not exists` is not supported in redshift for this function. Is there a way I can update workaround the lack of 'not exists' as a parameter so that one script can update all?

Answer (score 0):

The [CREATE GROUP - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_GROUP.html) documentation does *not* include such an option.

Some options:

- Call `DROP GROUP` first, and ignore any resulting errors, *or*
- You could possibly write a **Stored Procedure** that first checks `pg_group` for the existence of a group, then DROPs it if it exists, then create your desired group, *or*
- External to Redshift, query `pg_group` and call `DROP GROUP` if it exists, then create your desired group

Answer (score 0):

Based on [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675595/1479725). We created a stored procedure that creates a group if it does not already exist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_group_if_not_exists(name varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  existing varchar;
BEGIN
  SELECT groname INTO existing FROM pg_catalog.pg_group WHERE groname = name;
  IF existing IS NULL
  THEN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE GROUP ' || quote_ident(name) || ';';
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_group_if_exists(name varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  existing varchar;
BEGIN
  SELECT groname INTO existing FROM pg_catalog.pg_group WHERE groname = name;
  IF existing IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    EXECUTE 'DROP GROUP ' || quote_ident(name) || ';';
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```